# Are there any programming languages targeting PHP, besides Haxe?

Tags: php, programming-languages

PHP doesn't get much love but is still a winner at easy deployment (for cheap hosting).

Are there any programming languages (besides [Haxe](http://haxe.org/)) that target PHP? Writing applications in this language and then translating it into PHP, like some languages target C as an intermediate language?

- The [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)) implementation [Chicken](http://www.call-with-current-continuation.org/) compiles into [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_programming_language).
- [XOTcl](http://macroexpand.org/doku.php/txl:projects:java2tcl:start) converts [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) code into [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/) code
- LINJ was(?) a tool to convert Lisp into nice looking Java code
- …

+ a lot of ways to produce [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript) without touching JavaScript.

Comment: Needed to use tinyurl for the LINJ URL, because the link wasn't shown with the original URL.

Comment: @tylermac Because I already know about haXe.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473210

Answer (score 8):

[Pharen](http://github.com/scriptor/pharen), a Lisp variant.

Answer (score 4):

Kira
http://www.mathgladiator.com/projects/kira/

**EDIT:** Project stopped. New versions now don't target PHP anymore. New project is a web framework for C#.

Answer (score 2):

[PIL - Platform Independent Language](http://pil-lang.org/)

Answer (score -2):

Why?

php up to v 3.0 was pretty much a utility to hack html, version 4.0 was a very decent alternative to Perl or any other scripting language. Version 5.0 and up is a fully flegged OO language capable of solving many problems elegantly and efficiently.

The ' array() ' construct which behaves like an an array when you use integer subscripts and a hash when you use string subscripts is by far the most elegant and easy to use collection handling mechanism I have seen in any language. Arrays of Hashes, hashes of arrays, arrays of objects, nested tree structures are all acheived by straightforward coding with no special apis or declarations.

With the "batch" interface in v5.0 I predict that php is about to break out of the web/html ghetto and into more general use.